# unpivoting a sql table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

```
A_first B_first C_first  A_second  B_second  C_second A_third  B_third  C_third
638      450     188       638       439       187      546      256      789
```

I have a table like that with only one row. How can I pivot this row so I get `A` `B` `C` as columns and a row for each `_first`, `_second`, `_third`?

I'm trying to wrap my head around the pivot/unpivot command in sql

```
A          B      C     
638      450     188     
638      439     187     
546      256     789
```

Using SQL Server 2008 so I have the pivot/unpivot command. More specifically SSMS tells me the database I'm connected to is `9.0 SP3`

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: I added that information. Thankou

Comment: v9.0 = SQL Server **2005** - SQL Server 2008 would be "v10".

Comment: Oh I see. When I click about in SSMS, it says Microsft SQL Server 2008 R2. Maybe thats just the software installed on my local machine?\

Comment: That's most likely the version of the **SSMS** client-side tool - but that doesn't have to be the same as the engine. But for question like how to use certain features, the **engine version** of course is a lot more relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using so here are two solutions. If you have an `UNPIVOT` function and then a `PIVOT`:

```
select *
from
(
  select value, left(fields, 1) col,
    substring(fields, 3, len(fields) -2) row
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for fields in(A_first, B_first, C_first,
                  A_second, B_second, C_second,
                  A_third, B_third, C_third)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([A], [B], [C])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/651a4/10)

If you do not have an `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` function, then you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select
  max(case when col = 'A' then value end) A,
  max(case when col = 'B' then value end) B,
  max(case when col = 'C' then value end) C
from
(
  select value, left(fields, 1) col, substring(fields, 3, len(fields) -2) row
  from
  (
    select A_first value, 'A_first' fields
    from yourtable
    union all
    select B_first value, 'B_first' fields
    from yourtable
    union all
    select C_first value, 'C_first' fields
    from yourtable
    union all
    select A_second value, 'A_second' fields
    from yourtable
    union all
    select B_second value, 'B_second' fields
    from yourtable
    union all
    select C_second value, 'C_second' fields
    from yourtable
    union all
    select A_third value, 'A_third' fields
    from yourtable
    union all
    select B_third value, 'B_third' fields
    from yourtable
    union all
    select C_third value, 'C_third' fields
    from yourtable
  ) unpiv
) src
group by row
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/651a4/9)

Both will produce the same result:

```
|   A |   B |   C |
-------------------
| 638 | 450 | 188 |
| 638 | 439 | 187 |
| 546 | 256 | 789 |
```

Note, in order to perform this task the data types must be the same on each column. If they are not then you will need to `convert` the data first prior to the `UNPIVOT`.

This answer makes a few assumptions:

1. That the existing column will always start with the new column value (`A`,
   `B` or `C`, etc)
2. That the existing column will always start with two characters
   before the row number.

Comment: ... Except, he wants columns `A`, `B`, and `C`, not a row for each.  He wants rows for `_first`, `_second`, and `_third`

Comment: Thankyou, this helps a lot. However this is not the desired output. I am updating my post right now with my expected output.